# How does Javers handle frequent queries against json value fields when MySql doesn't support indexing for json?

Tags: mysql, json, indexing, audit, javers

I am using Javers with MySql.

Json can be stored in MySql, but is not usually recommended as MySql doesn't support indexing for json.

How does Javers handle frequent queries against json value fields when MySql doesn't support indexing for json?

I would appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

JaVers creates idexes for most fields that you can use in JQL queries - globalId, commitProperties, commitId. For now you cant query by objects' properties so indexing objects snapshots (json) is not required.